# Access 2013 issue. When deploy in a customer

Tags: ms-access

I have developed a Visual Basic 2013 application that works great on my computer. The problem occurs when I install it on the client computer. I used the forms, parameters as if I did not recognize the variables that happened to them in the forms.

Does anyone have any idea why ?. The Office version is 2013 on both sides. The difference is language. One in Spanish and the other in English.